# Chartjs v2 stroke shadow

Tags: javascript, html, chart.js

i would like to use a strokeshadow for my line chart. But every solution that i found works only with chartjs v1.

Is their any solution for the newest one?

thats what i designed with chartjs v1, but just like i said, i found no way to do it with version 2.

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7kbz1L4t/30/)

```
Chart.types.Line.extend({
  name: "LineAlt",
  initialize: function () {
    Chart.types.Line.prototype.initialize.apply(this, arguments);

    var ctx = this.chart.ctx;
    var originalStroke = ctx.stroke;
    ctx.stroke = function () {
      ctx.save();
      ctx.shadowColor = '#E56590';
      ctx.shadowBlur = 10;
      ctx.shadowOffsetX = 0;
      ctx.shadowOffsetY = 4;
      originalStroke.apply(this, arguments)
      ctx.restore();
    }
  }
});

var data = {
  labels: ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July"],
  datasets: [
    {
      label: "My First dataset",
      fillColor: "#fff",
      strokeColor: "#ffb88c",
      pointColor: "#fff",
      pointStrokeColor: "#ffb88c",
      pointHighlightFill: "#ffb88c",
      pointHighlightStroke: "#fff",
      data: [65, 59, 80, 81, 56, 55, 40]
    }
  ]
};


var ctx = document.getElementById("canvas").getContext("2d");
var myChart = new Chart(ctx).LineAlt(data, {
  datasetFill: false
});
```

Html:

```
<canvas id="canvas" width="600" height="300" style="background-color:#fff"></canvas>
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

**Yes!**

You could accomplish the same stroke shadow effect for line chart with *ChartJS v2* in the following way ...

```js
let draw = Chart.controllers.line.prototype.draw;
Chart.controllers.line = Chart.controllers.line.extend({
    draw: function() {
        draw.apply(this, arguments);
        let ctx = this.chart.chart.ctx;
        let _stroke = ctx.stroke;
        ctx.stroke = function() {
            ctx.save();
            ctx.shadowColor = '#E56590';
            ctx.shadowBlur = 10;
            ctx.shadowOffsetX = 0;
            ctx.shadowOffsetY = 4;
            _stroke.apply(this, arguments)
            ctx.restore();
        }
    }
});

let ctx = document.getElementById("canvas").getContext('2d');
let myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'line',
    data: {
        labels: ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July"],
        datasets: [{
            label: "My First dataset",
            data: [65, 59, 80, 81, 56, 55, 40],
            borderColor: '#ffb88c',
            pointBackgroundColor: "#fff",
            pointBorderColor: "#ffb88c",
            pointHoverBackgroundColor: "#ffb88c",
            pointHoverBorderColor: "#fff",
            pointRadius: 4,
            pointHoverRadius: 4,
            fill: false
        }]
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.5.0/Chart.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="canvas" width="600" height="300" style="background-color:#fff"></canvas>
```

Comment: @ℊααnd very nice solution. can you see how can i add shadow on my one. i tried but not really work. may be i mistake somewhere https://codepen.io/pagol/pen/VzrvWm

Comment: it works, but it also adds shadows to grid lines(shadows on grid lines barely visible). Is any way to create shadows only on dataset lines?

Comment: @Ashot check my answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49191402/add-shadown-for-line-in-vue-chartjs/49193942#49193942

Answer (score 1):

The proper answer is given on [this issue at the github page for Chart.js](https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/issues/4977) by etimberg and Ashot-KR.

See [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dces93wv/) for the work in action, the red line is the shadow.

Adopted from the fiddle, giving a proper shadow, include this code:

```
(function()
{
    var ShadowLineElement = Chart.elements.Line.extend({
        draw: function()
        {
            var ctx = this._chart.ctx;
            var originalStroke = ctx.stroke;
            ctx.stroke = function()
            {
                ctx.save();
                ctx.shadowColor = 'rgba(0,0,0,0.4)';
                ctx.shadowBlur = 2;
                ctx.shadowOffsetX = 0.5;
                ctx.shadowOffsetY = 0.5;
                originalStroke.apply(this, arguments);
                ctx.restore();
            };
            Chart.elements.Line.prototype.draw.apply(this, arguments);
            ctx.stroke = originalStroke;
        }
    });
    Chart.defaults.ShadowLine = Chart.defaults.line;
    Chart.controllers.ShadowLine = Chart.controllers.line.extend({
        datasetElementType: ShadowLineElement
    });
})();
```

And then change the dataset type from `type: 'line'` to `type: 'ShadowLine'`.