# add shadow for line in vue chartjs

Tags: chart.js, vue-chartjs

I want to add shadow for the line in my chart.

My code is like so

```
   import { Line } from 'vue-chartjs'
    import Chart  from 'chart.js'

    let draw = Chart.controllers.line = Chart.controllers.line.extend({
    draw: function() {
            let ctx = this.chart.chart.ctx;
        ctx.save();
        ctx.shadowColor = 'red';
        ctx.shadowBlur = 12;
        ctx.shadowOffsetX = 0;
        ctx.shadowOffsetY = 5;
        ctx.stroke();
        draw.apply(this, arguments);
        ctx.restore();
    }
});

    const BasicLineChart = {
      extends: Line,
      props: ['data', 'options'],
      mounted () {
        const options = this.options || {
            responsive: true, 
            maintainAspectRatio: false,
            borderWidth: 1,
            legend: {
                display: false
            },
            scales: {
                yAxes: [{
                    position: 'right',
                    scaleLabel: {
                        display: false,
                        labelString: 'Pris',
                        fontFamily: 'apercu-light',
                    },
                    gridLines: {
                        display:true,
                        color: 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6)'
                    },
                    ticks: {
                        beginAtZero:false,
                        mirror: true
                    }
                }],
                xAxes: [{
                    ticks: {
                        display: true,
                    },
                    scaleLabel: {
                        display: false,
                    },
                    gridLines: {
                        display:true,
                        color: 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6)'
                    }
                }]
            }
        }

        this.renderChart(this.data, options)
    }
}

    export default {
        props: ['id'],
        components: {
            BasicLineChart,
        },
        created() {
            this.draw()
        },
        data() {
            return {
                chartData: {},
                showChart: false
            }
        },
        methods: {
            draw() {
                axios.get('url/' + this.id).then(({ data })=> {
                    this.showChart = true;
                })
            } 
        }
    };
```

With that code I was able to add the shadow for line. However the grids for added blue shadow as well, which is not desired behavior. The grids should not have any shadow.

The screen shot of the shadow on grids and line. Notice the slighly blue shade along the grids line? I want to get rid of it

[image]

What could be done to get rid of the shadow on the grids ?

UPDATED:

I updated the code as suggested. I got this error

```
app.js?v=79:76561 Uncaught TypeError: this.chart.getDatasetMeta is not a function
    at ChartElement.getMeta (app.js?v=79:76561)
    at ChartElement.linkScales (app.js?v=79:76545)
    at ChartElement.initialize (app.js?v=79:76535)
    at ChartElement.Chart.DatasetController (app.js?v=79:76514)
    at ChartElement [as constructor] (app.js?v=79:5711)
    at ChartElement [as constructor] (app.js?v=79:5711)
    at ChartElement.draw (app.js?v=79:71285)
    at Chart.drawDataset (app.js?v=79:76122)
    at Chart.drawDatasets (app.js?v=79:76097)
    at Chart.draw (app.js?v=79:76061)
```

Answer (score 3):

Try changing `Chart.controllers.line.extend` to this:

```
Chart.controllers.line = Chart.controllers.line.extend({
    draw: function() {
        let ctx = this.chart.chart.ctx;
        ctx.save();
        ctx.shadowColor = 'red';
        ctx.shadowBlur = 12;
        ctx.shadowOffsetX = 0;
        ctx.shadowOffsetY = 5;
        ctx.stroke();
        draw.apply(this, arguments);
        ctx.restore();
    }
});
```

to avoid `stroke()` method stay redefined also for gridlines drawing.

Check this example (non vue.js): https://jsfiddle.net/beaver71/aorgfd0z/

Comment: I use the suggested code. Got 'Uncaught TypeError: this.chart.getDatasetMeta is not a function'

Comment: Are you using latest version of Chart.js (2.7.2)? See docs (http://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/developers/api.html#getdatasetmetaindex)

Comment: Provide your own fiddle using Vue.js and I'll check it

Comment: working on the fiddle. By the way, your Y axis also has shadow. The shadow should be on the line only

Answer (score 0):

```
      let draw = Chart.controllers.line.prototype.draw;
      Chart.helpers.extend(Chart.controllers.line.prototype, {
        draw: function () {
          let ctx = this.chart.ctx;
          ctx.save();
          ctx.shadowColor = "rgba(54, 54, 54, 0.2)";
          ctx.shadowBlur = 5;
          ctx.shadowOffsetX = 0;
          ctx.shadowOffsetY = 4;
          draw.apply(this, arguments);
          ctx.restore();
        },
      });
```

Use this way, shadows won't appear on your gridlines, also if you are using `annotation line` then also it won't give any problem to you.
I have implemented this in Vue.js